# jQuery.validate doesn't work with ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've successfully made a working jQuery.validation form for my site in just HTML, CSS and JS (with dependencies: jQuery and Validation). The problem is when I'm in a clean ASP.NET Core web project and I use the exact same code, it just doesn't seem to use my custom validation parameters in JavaScript

The validation works in all cases. However, my custom `[options]` for `.validate([options])` don't seem to work on ASP.NET Core

Example of the working code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhhxmy1t/8/)

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">
<fieldset>
    <div class="master">
      <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" minlength="2" maxlength="40" required />
    </div>
    <div class="master">
      <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" required />
    </div>
    <div class="master">
      <input name="company" placeholder="Company Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="master">
      <input name="website" placeholder="Website" type="url" required />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Next</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.master {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.has-error {
  background-color: red;
}

.has-success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('form').validate({
    // This disables the default validation notifications to the user.
    // Instead I'll be using CSS colors to notify users of valid or invalid fields
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { },

    // Invalid field produces a red-background in parent element
    highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
  },

  // Valid field produces a green-background in parent element
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
  }
});
```

My JavaScript `.validate([options])` does 3 things:

1. Remove jQuery.validation's default notification option
2. If `<field>` is **INVALID**, parent element background-color is **red**
3. If `<field>` is **VALID**, parent element background-color is **green**

---

**Note:**

- Updated my ASP.NET Core (1.1) to the latest stable version

  - Downgraded to ASP.NET Core 1.0 to test
- Added latest jQuery via bower, local and CDN (for testing)
- Added latest Validate via bower, local and CDN (for testing)

  - According to Validate's website certain versions of jQuery has to be used for compatibility. I tested all the versions via bower, local and CDN
- Made a raw HTML, CSS and JS version with everything stripped out (*dependencies included*) in JSFiddle, CodePen and local. **Everything worked perfectly** but not in ASP project.
- External or Inline JavaScript, no changes.

---

**My conclusion:**
The validation works in all cases, which means both ASP.NET Core applications and plain HTML - CSS - JS have properly functional validation.

The only thing that **doesn't work** is when I provide `[options]` in my `$('form').validate([options]);` in a ASP.NET Core application. I'm not sure why my options aren't being used.

Official jQuery.validate page on [.validate([options])](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)

Comment: Doubtful that this has anything to do with ASP.Net (Core or otherwise) per se - _other_ than referencing the scripts/css (paths, etc.). End of day client is client, server is server (latter is where all flavors of ASP.Net play).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out the problem. It had to do with jQuery.validate(`[option]`) object property: `success`

It directly conflicts with two other properties: `highlight` and `unhighlight`

For example:

```
$('form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { },

    highlight: function (element) {
        // Do stuff
    },

    unhighlight: function (element) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    success: function (element) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

The `success` property completely uses a different way of notifying the user of invalid fields via tooltips. Where as `highlight` and `unhighlight` has more of a custom way for the developer to have more control.

In ASP.NET Core since jQuery.validate comes shipped with every ASP.NET Core Web Application, it applies its own `success` property as apart of its scaffolding somewhere within build.

The way I got around this is by explicitly calling my JS script last and placing a callback to any function within the `success` function.